# Upload Image from IntentService when the app is closed

Tags: android, service, upload, alarmmanager, intentservice

I'm developing an app that synchronize your local date with the cloud. So I need to check automatically, each 10 minutes, my local data to get the new camera files to upload to the cloud.

So I have used an IntentService that works only when the app is running in foreground. If I close it, my service doesn't upload anything.And I WANT MY INTENTSERVICE WORKS IN BACKGROUND with the AlarmManager.

My IntentService is declared in Manifest.xml:

```
    <!-- Uploader and Deleter Files  Service -->
     <service android:name=".receiver.UploadDeleteService"   android:exported="false" />
    <receiver
        android:name=".receiver.AlarmReceiver"
        android:process=":remote" >
    </receiver>
```

My AlarmReceiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 12345;
    public static final String ACTION = "com.codepath.example.servicesdemo.alarm";

    // Triggered by the Alarm periodically (starts the service to run task)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, UploadDeleteService.class);
        context.startService(i);
    }
```

}

My ServiceInteractor where I instance my AlarmReceiver inside AlarmManager:

```
public class ServiceInteractorImpl implements ServiceInteractor {

private Context context;

public ServiceInteractorImpl(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void launchService() {

    // Construct an intent that will execute the AlarmReceiver
    Intent intent =  new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    // Create a PendingIntent to be triggered when the alarm goes off
    final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, AlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    // Setup periodic alarm every 5 seconds
    long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); // alarm is set right away
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    // First parameter is the type: ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, RTC_WAKEUP
    // Interval can be INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, INTERVAL_HOUR, INTERVAL_DAY
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
    alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis,
            cal.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);

}
```

}

My UploadDeleteService where I call to the retrofit implementation module:

```
 public class UploadDeleteService extends IntentService implements ApiConnector.GetObjectListener {

    private RemoteInteractor remoteInteractor;

    public UploadDeleteService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public UploadDeleteService() {
        super("UpdateDeleteService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i("SERVICE", "Service running");
        remoteInteractor = new RemoteInteractorImpl(getApplicationContext());
        remoteInteractor.checkNews(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onImageUploaded(String type, JSONObject response) {
        Log.d("SERVICE", "  onImageUploaded  ");
       //REST OF THE STUFF....
    }
}
```

Please I need a helping hand to solve that problem. I need it works each 10 minutes although the app is closed. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the service is repeate on foreground.

Comment: cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 10); //this will add 10 minute to current time try to change "cal.getTimeInMillis()" to "10*60*1000"

Comment: That was the error, thanks. But does anybody know how to avoid my service opens the app when alarm manager takes control?

Answer (score 1):

**For stopped Service:**

change "cal.getTimeInMillis()" to "10*60*1000"

```
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 10); //this will add 10 minute to current time
```

**For Stopped open app when service start:**

normally it will not open your app, you need to check what happened in RemoteInteractorImpl.class

you create new instance at `onHandleIntent`

```
remoteInteractor = new RemoteInteractorImpl(getApplicationContext());
remoteInteractor.checkNews(this);
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution Sally! I actually had some lines inside checkNews where I used a Intent to start an activity, and that was the reason my app opened itself every time the AlarmManager took control.Cheers!